# Adb pull database from android device

Tags: android, adb

I know how to pull `db` from android device through `adb` but i have got few samsung device like S4 `adb` is not working. when I run

> `run-as packagename`

It says package does not exist and it works in other devices.
Any idea why it is happening like that??

Answer (score 2):

You can also get the db file from Eclipse/studio

- Open DDMS ==> File explorer tab
- Move to `/data/data/your packagename/databases`
- Select the required `.db` file and  press pull button. (You will find it on top right corner of file explored) and save the file  at required location

(OR)

Go to command prompt

```
c:> adb pull /data/data/your packagename/databases/dbfilename.db  savefilelocation(ex: /username/Desktop/x.db)
```

Comment: @abforce  1. First option can be used only for rooted device. 2.Second option can be used for unrooted device and I have mentioned that I know how to use it. But it does not work with all devices. For Eg : Samsung S4. So please read the query carefully.